# <aui:button> not working after deploying project into AWS

Tags: liferay-7, liferay-theme, liferay-aui, liferay-7.1, liferay-7.2

In jsp created some buttons using `<aui:button>`, In local those buttons are `working as expected` but after deploying project into AWS, Buttons are not working. i inspected button  on clicking button nothing showing in console.

This is code creating buttons

```
<portlet:actionURL name="<%= MVCCommandNames.SAVE_CART_LIST_PRODUCT %>" var="addProductToCartURL" >
     <portlet:param name="productId" value="${productId}" />
     <portlet:param name="isWishlisted" value="${isWishlisted}" />
     <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/product.jsp" />
</portlet:actionURL>

<div class="button-row" >
    <div class="a-button-1"  >
        <c:if test="${!isCartListed}">
             <button class="crt-btn-wish add-to-crt-btn" type="submit" onclick="checkSize(event)" >ADD TO CART</button>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${isCartListed}">
            <aui:button class="crt-btn-wish go-to-crt-btn" type="button"value="Go to Cart ->" />
        </c:if>
    </div>
    <div class="a-button-2" >
        <c:if test="${!isWishlisted}">

           <portlet:actionURL name="<%= MVCCommandNames.SAVE_WISHLIST_PRODUCT %>" var="addProductToWishlistURL" >
                <portlet:param name="productId" value="${productId}" />
                <portlet:param name="isCartListed" value="${isCartListed}" />
                <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/product.jsp" />
            </portlet:actionURL>

            <aui:button cssClass="crt-btn-wish add-to-wish-btn" href="${addProductToWishlistURL}"  type="button" value="ADD TO WISHLIST" />
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${isWishlisted}">
            <aui:button cssClass="crt-btn-wish go-to-wish-btn" href="${viewWishlistProductURL}"  type="button" value="Go to Wishlist ->" />
        </c:if>
    </div>
</div>
```

This project is created by version `portal-7.1-ga3`,
Is there anything required to do before deploying project.